# GDB debug core dump. Can not find local variable

Tags: gdb

I'm learning how to use GDB now. And I'm having some trouble diagnosing what went wrong.

When I run a `bt full`, I have the following result:

```
(gdb) bt full 
#0  0x43675798 in memcpy ()
   from /armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0001e8c4 in write_utf8_string ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x0001dd80 in connect ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x0000f940 in connect_to_broker ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x0000fe24 in network ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x0000c0a8 in configuration_client ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x0000f1b4 in connection_threaded ()
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x437761b0 in start_thread ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x436cddb0 in ?? ()
   from armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I think the problem happened at `frame 0` the `memcpy` function. But since I used `memcpy` a lot I'm not sure which one is causing the problem. So I go to `frame 1` and prints all the arguments I parsed to this function. But The GDB did not find any of the arg I passed:

```
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x0001e8c4 in write_utf8_string ()
(gdb) print ptr
No symbol "ptr" in current context.
(gdb) print conn_config->MQTTVersion
No symbol "conn_config" in current context.
(gdb) print MQTTVersion
No symbol "MQTTVersion" in current context.
(gdb) print clientID
No symbol "clientID" in current context.
(gdb) print clientIDLen
No symbol "clientIDLen" in current context.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening or the arg is corrupted before this frame. But I check all the arguments in all the functions listed in the bt. The GDB can not find any of them.

Also I'm not sure what the `??` mean in the `frame 8`

Comment: You need to build with debug info enabled, typically with `-g` option.

Comment: Ahh yes. Thank you. That is the problem :D